# Iphone Interaction with server to minimise loads with new rules.

Tags: ios, swift, rest, servlets, https

I am writing an IOS application in swift 3 that will need to pull data from a server every so often but will not need to send (post) anything.

I was thinking of setting up an HTTP server and use GET requests to get the data from the server. Recently apple announced that they will now require all HTTP interactions to be HTTPS. This is quite computational expensive and I have never set a HTTPS server up.

I have seen somewhere a recommendation to use a TCP/IP socket, but I think it would be rather wasteful to keep a socket open when only a bit of data will be needed from a user every few minutes.

This is the first time I am building this type of system.

What are the industry standard ways of going about creating short connections between an IOS app and a server?

How would you recommend I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly the difference in time to execute a HTTPS request is minimal. The computational cost opinion is a little outdated. For example a 2012 Macbook air can sign an SSL certificate in about 6.3 milliseconds.

setting up a https server is exactly the same as setting up a HTTP server apart from changing the configuration for SSL. Combined with purchasing an SSL certificate for your website, then configuring and installing it with the domain.

Or you could use firebase which is free and provides SSL as standard. Which removes the need to actually set up a server yourself. https://firebase.google.com